# как добавить cardview в приложение?

Tags: java, android, android-material

Приветсвую! Как можно добавить в андроид приложение cardview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... >
    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

gradle

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=ru#Dependencies

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно что бы приложение было для андроид 4х+

Comment: android.support.v7 - это и есть библиотека совместимости, в том числе для Андроидов 4+. Смело добавляйте.